# validate hardcoded value in rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a registration form where user has to enter his credentials plus a textfield called as promotion code. So the form can be submitted only when the promotion code's value is "akpoi". So the user has to enter this string for form submission, Otherwise it would display error message to user as "akpoi should be entered in promotional code field". How do I check this in rails model validation??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be check on the controller side

```
if params[:field_name] == "akpoi"

else

end
```

If u insist to do it in model do following

```
after_validation :check_field_value

def check_field_value
  self.errors.add(:comment, "Add Your Error Here") if field_name != "akpoi"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you would want to use `inclusion`:

```
validates :promo_code, :presence => true,:inclusion => { :in => "akpoi" }
```